# Can carbonated water produce addiction in humans?

Tags: nutrition, addiction, food-addiction, carbonated-carbonation, thirst-thirsty

Recently I have been quite heavily drinking beer, and noticed a strange effect: apparently an addiction developed but not to alcohol but to CO2.

Basically, now I cannot satisfy my thristyness with non-carbonated drinks, such as tap water, tea and milk.

Today I felt thristyness all the day despite drinking a lot of milk products and tap water. All the day I was drinking and pissing, but still was thristy. Finally, after 4th glass of tap water in a row, without any hope to combat my thristyness I went to a store and took a bottle of carbonated mineral water.

Instantly when I started drinking it my eyes filled with tears of satisfaction and the thristyness went away.

So, I suspect I developed some kind of dependence on CO2 dissolved in water.

Comment: Most carbonated mineral water is a little salty. It's possible you were low on electrolytes. This has nothing to do with being addicted, but just that you needed something, Next time you feel that way try eating a salty snack and see if you experience the same relief.

Comment: @Kate Gregory no, salty food (such as fish) does not help. Also, there is salty milk product "Tan" which has carbonated and non-carbonated versions, and only carbonated one reduces thristyness. I suspect, this is because CO2 affects drink receptors stronger, so that normal drink no longer felt by those receptors.

Comment: there is no such thing as "drink receptors" though

Comment: Please note that constant thirst is a common indicator of Type 2 diabetes. I was diagnosed because of my constant thirst, so I can speak from personal experience. My diabetes is now under control, but I still crave liquids when my blood sugar gets even a little elevated. Flavored seltzer water is the only thing that works for me.